# Running a function from a string

Tags: python, function

I need to call a function whose name is available in a string in python 
eg:

```
   [(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y]
```

I need to execute the above statement but the variable count may increase according to user input any idea?

Another Example :

```
a = "for y in range(2,20):print y"
```

I need to execute the above string as a python command

Actual Problem is no of loops and variable may increase depends upon the input 
somtimes i wnat to iterate over 3 item so 3 loops sometime 4 item then 4 loops 
so i figured out this way if i generate string with the variables and if i can execute it problem can be solved

Comment: Err, where's the string?

Comment: You said the variable count may increase, do you mean the list? Can you explain again what do you want?

Comment: `getattr` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr is what you need, your question is very low quality though...

Comment: example:
    a = "for y in range(1,20):print y"
i need to execute the string as python function

Comment: oh right, that's probably better.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: wouldn't work for the given string.

Comment: @Sreevisakh I am still not sure what are you asking for :(

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be a poor man's version of [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.tee#itertools.permutations):  a `set()` (well, in this case, a comparison) used to exclude the duplicates that could be gathered from `itertools.product`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `eval` function is what you are looking for:

```
s = "[(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y]"
result = eval(s)
```

If you want variables, you can use the `locals` argument:

```
>>> eval("s.upper()",{'s':'hello'})
'HELLO'
```

If you want to execute statements instead of evaluating expressions, use `exec`:

```
>>> a = "for y in range(2,20):print y"
>>> exec a
2
3
...
19
```

Comment: You may want to suggest a warning or two about security? `Eval` is good, but only in a controlled environment.

Comment: `eval` doesn't seems to work in the way i want
what i given the above string to eval it resulted in syntax error

Comment: @Droogans: Right. I hope input is not from an untrusted user :)

Comment: @Sreev If you have a statement, use exec instead. Only expressions can be evaluated with eval. "for" and "print" are examples of statements.